# How would you write files to s3 in parallel? i.e. not serialized one by one

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-s3

I have 10K files to write to S3 every hour, how can I do this in parallel?

Comment: I think a little more context would be useful here, might help some people get started on answers.

Comment: http://bhapca.blogspot.com/2010/07/how-to-upload-in-bulk-to-amazon-s3.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use multiple threads or try EventMachine with a S3 driver. You need to a throughput of about 3 files per second which depending on the file size shouldn't be that hard. Make sure to use HTTP keep-alive to not reconnect in between each file.